# Template argument deduction in function signature using guide

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

let's say you have a class `A` (C++17):

```
template<class T>
struct A
{
    A() = default;
    A(T t) : val(t)
    {
    }
    A operator*(A a)
    {
        return A(a.val * this->val);
    }

    T val;
};
```

However, 99% of the time the value-type of `A` is going to be an `int`, so you use a deduction guide to reduce the verbosity:

```
A()->A<int>;
```

So that's cool, now you can define variables without the template list:

```
A myVar;
```

The problem I'm having is that it seems to break down when it comes to function signatures, for example the following requires use of a template argument list:

```
auto ASquared = [](A a, A b) { return a * b; };
```

> error C2955: 'A': use of class template requires template argument
>   list

When I wanted it to deduce that `A` was `A<int>`.

My question is: is this an inherent limitation, or am I just missing a different deduction guide that could make this syntax work?

Comment: The error that clang gives is `error: use of class template 'A' requires template arguments; argument deduction not allowed in lambda parameter`.

Comment: You know that you can just use a default template argument, right? `template <class T = int>`

Comment: @Brian yes it's an MCVE for a real problem I'm having that does require the use of guides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language doesn't allow this. Deduction doesn't take place within a function signature because there's nothing to deduce from.